# Why cat 0>file doesn't work

Tags: linux, unix, stdout, stdin, cat

In Unix, I know that 0 1 and 2 represent stdin stdout and stderr.

As my understanding, the command `cat` meaning "concatenate" can concatenate different files.

For example, `cat file>&1` can concatenate the `file` and the stdout and the arrow means the redirection from the `file`to the stdout, so we can see the content of the `file` from the terminal which is stdout.

But, I don't understand why the command below doesn't work:
`cat 0>file`

I think this command should work, because it means that to concatenate the stdin and the `file` and do the redirection from the stdin to the `file`.
However it doesn't work and I get an error:

> cat: input error on standard input: Bad file number

I thought that `cat > file` and `cat 0>file` are exactly the same, just like `cat file` and `cat file>&1` are exactly the same, but it seems I'm wrong...

To my surprise, `cat 1>file` and `cat > file` are the same. Why?

Comment: `>` isn't concatenate: it's overwrite. Concatenate is `>>`.

Comment: @Ruslan OK. `cat 0>>file` doesn't work either.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the logic behind trying to `cat` stdin and a file?

Comment: @PeterK  In fact, I'm considering how `cat > file` works. I think it works as `cat 0>file` but it seems I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax `0>file` redirects `stdin` into a file (if that makes sense). Then `cat` tries to read from `stdin` and gets `EBADF` error because `stdin` is no longer an input stream.

> `EBADF` - fd is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for reading.

Note that redirections (< and >) are handled by the shell, cat does not see `0>file` bit.

Comment: so we can't write commands like `0>...` but we can write `1>...` and `2>...`, meaning that stdout and stderr are valid file discriptors whereas stdin isn't?

Comment: @Thomas I cannot explain it better than http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: It may be possible to make `stdin` redirected into a file, but then code must treat `stdin` as output stream, which is rather odd.

Comment: This link is very good but I'm confused now. It seems that `cat 1>file`, instead of `cat 0>file`, is the same with `cat > file`. Why? `cat > file` is to input things into `file`. Why is it stdout, instead of stdin to redirect to the `file`...

Comment: @Thomas `cat` reads _input_ from `stdin` and the files specified in its command line; and _outputs_ into `stdout`.

Comment: ahhhh OK, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `cat` prints the contents of a file or from the stdin. If you don't provide a file and redirect the stdin to a file, then `cat` doesn't have any input to read from.

The correct form would be: `cat <&0 > file.txt`, that is:

- `<&0` redirect stdin as input for `cat` (similar to `cat < some-file.txt`)
- `> file.txt` redirect the output of `cat` to `file.txt`

This works both for:

- `echo "hello" | cat <&0 > file.txt`, that is, piping the output of some command
- `cat <&0 > file.txt` as stand alone and you type directly on the console (quit with Ctrl-d)

As a side note:

```sh
# This works (no errors) as cat has a file in input, but:
# 1. the contents of some-file-with-contents.txt will be printed out
# 2. file.txt will not contain anything
cat some-file-with-contents.txt 0>file.txt

# This works (no errors) as cat has a file in input, but:
# 1. the contents of some-file-with-contents.txt will be printed out
# 2. file.txt will not contain anything
# 3. copy.txt will have the contents of some-file-with-contents.txt
cat some-file-with-contents.txt 0>file.txt 1>copy.txt
```

Comment: Great, very helpful. Thanks. BTW, to quit `cat <&0 > file.txt`, `Ctrl-d` should be more standard.

Comment: `<&0` doesn’t **do** anything, though, since it obtains the value for descriptor 0 from itself.